# Add removeClass function in my Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck for this problem more than a week -_-. What I need to do is add the removeclass function in my jQuery validation below. In bid and rfq validation add the removeclass.

I have dropdown and two textbox (rfq and bid), when I select BIDDING in dropdown the bid textbox hide. But the problem is when I tried to submit the validation requirements comes out bcoz the textbox bid doesn't have a value. So I tried to add a removeclass function in textbox depends on dropdown value.

This is my working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mHCk7/4/

Part of Validation jQuery

```
if (bid == "") {
    $("span.val_bid").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
}
else {
    if (!bid_regex.test(bid)) { // if invalid phone
        $("span.val_bid").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    }
    else {
        $("span.val_bid").html("");
    }
}
if (rfq == "") {
    $("span.val_rfq").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
    validation_holder = 1;
}
else {
    if (!rfq_regex.test(rfq)) { // if invalid phone
        $("span.val_rfq").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    }
    else {
        $("span.val_rfq").html("");
    }
}
```

Remove Class jquery

```
$('#txt1').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING' || $(this).val() == '') {
        $("#txt2,#txt3").val('');
        $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
        $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'BIDDING') {
        $("#txt3").val('');
        $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'RFQ') {
        $("#txt2").val('');
        $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
    }
    else {
        //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to call/add the $('#txt1').change() function inside your validation part?

Comment: trigger the $('#txt1').change() function in bid and rfq validation

Comment: @Vinoth I updated my question. I want to connect the removeclass function in my validation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mHCk7/7/ see this

Comment: @SIST Solutons , he has to submit the form is valid. jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/mHCk7/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might take a stab on this one. in BID_RFQ() you have the hide/show functionality of all your input fields. What else you could do is to add/remove mandatory class from input fields from ones that should/shouldn't have it. Ie:

```
function BID_RFQ() {
    if($("#txt1").val() =="BIDDING"){
        $("#bid").css({visibility:'visible', overflow: 'visible'});
        $("#txt2").addClass("mandatory");
        $("#rfq").css({visibility:'hidden', overflow: 'hidden'});
        $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
    if($("#txt1").val() =="RFQ"){
        $("#bid").css({visibility:'hidden', overflow: 'hidden'});
        $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
        $("#rfq").css({visibility:'visible', overflow: 'visible'});
        $("#txt3").addClass("mandatory");
    } else {
        $("#bid").css({visibility:'hidden', overflow: 'hidden'});
        $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
        $("#rfq").css({visibility:'hidden', overflow: 'hidden'});
        $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
    }
    return true;
}
```

So this will help you to find out if each input is required when doing validation. For simplicity, you can even:

```
var rfq = $("form#register_form input[name='n_rfq']").val();
var rfq_regex = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
var rfq_mandatory =  $("#txt3").hasClass("mandatory");
var bid = $("form#register_form input[name='n_bid']").val();
var bid_regex = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
var bid_mandatory =  $("#txt2").hasClass("mandatory");
```

So when doing validation, you can:

```
if(bid == "" && bid_mandatory)
AND 
if(!bid_regex.test(bid) && bid_mandatory)
```

[JS Fiddle can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mHCk7/24/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code

```
<script>var FormValidation = function(form){


         this.messages = {

            required    : 'This field should not be empty',
            email       : 'Please enter  valid email',
            number      : 'Please enter  valid number',
            min         : 'This field length should be minimum ',
            max         : 'This field length should not exceed ',
            range       : 'This field length between  '
        };

        validator = this;

        var currentmsg =this;

        this.required = function(value){
            var valid = (value.length > 0);
            return {status: valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.required};
        }

        this.email = function(value){
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/ ;
            var valid = pattern.test(value);
            return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.email};
        }

        this.number = function(value){
            var pattern = /^[0-9]+/ ;
            var valid = pattern.test(value);
            return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.number};
        }

        this.min = function(value,args){
            if(value.length > 0){
                var valid = (value.length >= args[0])
                return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.min + args[0] };
            }
        }

        this.max = function(value,args){
                if(value.length > 0){
                    var valid = (value.length <= args[0])
                    return { status:valid, message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.max + args[0] };
                }
            }

        this.range = function(value,args){
            var valid = (value.length >= args[0] && value.length <= args[1])
            return { 
                status:valid, 
                message: valid ? '' : currentmsg.messages.range + args[0] + ' and ' + args[1]
                };
        }

        this.validators = {
            required : validator.required,
            email    : validator.email,
            number   : validator.number,
            range    : validator.range,
            max      : validator.max,
            min      : validator.min 
        };

        this.validate = function(form){
            var elements = form.elements;
            console.log('elements', elements);
            var status = true;
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++){
                var validate = elements[i].getAttribute('validate');
                if(!validate){      
                    continue;
                }
                var types = validate.split(' ');
                for(var j = 0; j < types.length; j++){
                    var result = this.validateField(elements[i], types[j]);
                    if(!result) { 
                        continue 
                    }
                    this.displayErrors(elements[i], result);
                    if(!result.status) {                            
                        status = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return status;
        }

        this.displayErrors = function(element, result){
            element.className = result.status ? '' : 'error';
            var elErr =element.errorMsg;
            if(elErr!=null)
                elErr.className = result.status ? '' :'valerr'
                if(!element.errorMsg){
                    elErr = document.createElement("span");
                    elErr.id = 'valerr';
                    element.parentNode.appendChild(elErr);
                    element.errorMsg = elErr;
                }
            elErr.innerHTML = result.message;
        }

        this.validateField = function (element, type){
            var validationType = type;
            var args ;
            if(type.indexOf("(")!= -1 && type.indexOf(")") != -1){
                var result = this.getArguments(type);
                validationType = result.type;
                args = result.argsList;
            }
            validator = this.validators[validationType];
            if(validator != null){
                return validator(element.value ,args);
            }
            return null;
        }

        this.getArguments = function(type){
            var validationtype = type.substring(0,type.indexOf("("));
            var args = type.substring(type.indexOf("(")+1,type.indexOf(")")).split(',');
            return { type : validationtype, argsList : args}
        }

        this.init = function() {
               var curForm = this;
               $('#register_form').on('submit', function(){
               console.log('valid',curForm.validate(this));
               return curForm.validate(this);
            });     
        }
}
function init() {

    var names = { 'BIDDING':'n_bid', 'RFQ': 'n_rfq' }       
            var p = $('#optional-field');
    var temp = $('<div>');
    addDynamicField = function(label){
          var label = $('<label>').text(label);
              var input = $('<input>').attr('type','text').attr('name',names[label]).attr('validate','required number');
      temp.empty().append(label).append(input);
              p.empty().html(temp.html());

    }
    hideDynamicField  = function() {
      p.empty();
    }
    $('#options').change(function(){
       var option = $(this).val();
       if(option == 'RFQ' || option == 'BIDDING'){
         addDynamicField($(this).val());    
       } else {
         hideDynamicField();    
       }    
    });

    addDynamicField('BIDDING','n_bid');

    var formValidation = new FormValidation();
    formValidation.init();

}init(); 

<div id="wrap"> <!--wrap start-->
    <div id="wrap2">  <!--wrap2 start-->

    <h2 class="free_account">Add Records</h2> 
<form action="po_insert.php" method="post" id="register_form"  name="register_form" >
    <div id="formFields">
       <p class="validate_msg">Please fix the errors below!</p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Mode of Procurement</label>
        <select name="n_mode" id="options" type="text">
            <option value="BIDDING">BIDDING</option>
            <option value="RFQ">RFQ</option>
            <option value="NEGOTIATED">NEGOTIATED</option>
            <option value="SHOPPING">SHOPPING</option>
        </select>
        <span class="val_mode"></span>
    </p>      
    <p id="optional-field"></p>
    <p> 
        <label for="">Quantity</label> 
        <input type="text" name="n_quantity" id="txtbox3" validate="required number">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" id="sbtBtn">
</form>
```

Comment: The error is bcoz the hidden textbox doesn't have a value. Bcoz I need to hide it depends on the value of select dropdown

Comment: now i got your point. select ":visible" elements while doing validation. https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: What should I do? Help please :/

Comment: Ok I'll wait. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please wait. i am doing that

Comment: Here i updated your code. look at into it and if u have any doubts u can comment. please vote up and mark this as answer if it is working for you . http://jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/mHCk7/26/

Answer (score 0):

the problem over here is actually the removeClass function is called in your change function, but before that from your function which is BID_RFQ(), you are making the visibility hidden for the text boxes.

comment the code which makes the visibility hidden in your else part..

```
function BID_RFQ()
{
if(document.register_form.n_mode.options[document.register_form.n_mode.selectedIndex].value=="BIDDING"){document.getElementById("bid").style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById("bid").style.overflow='visible';document.getElementById("rfq").style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById("rfq").style.overflow='hidden';}
else if(document.register_form.n_mode.options[document.register_form.n_mode.selectedIndex].value=="RFQ"){document.getElementById("rfq").style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById("rfq").style.overflow='visible';document.getElementById("bid").style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById("bid").style.overflow='hidden';}
    else{//document.getElementById("bid").style.visibility='hidden';//document.getElementById("bid").style.overflow='hidden';//document.getElementById("rfq").style.visibility='hidden';//document.getElementById("rfq").style.overflow='hidden';}return true;
}
```

Comment: you can see in the last else part, i comment all the code which hides the text boxes

Comment: it affects the hide function

Comment: if you are hiding the text boxes, then how can you display the mandatory class there?

Answer (score 0):

use validation_holder = 0; in your else part and set condition:

```
if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        } 
        if(validation_holder == 0)
        {
         $("p.validate_msg").hide("slow");
        }
```

Comment: but it doesn't submit the form -_-

Comment: your just submitting the form without the requirements of textbox -_-. Please take a look of my question.